# OnMouseDown() called for only the foremost GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

[image: example of situation]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/2WcSy3QSAqu5))</sub>

I have a BoxCollider2D component and a script attached to the black and red boxes. Each script with some things to happen in a OnMouseDown() function. The problem is if I click on the part of the orange box that overlaps the black one, the OnMouseDown() of the black box will be called but I want only the orange box function to be called.

How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think OnMouseDown is a great approach here. You can use [2D RayCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) to only get the top most collider. You are going to have to account for sorting layer and sorting order on your own with this approach.

The trick to checking a single point in 2D is to not give the raycast direction as shown below with:

```
Physics2D.Raycast(touchPostion, Vector2.zero);
```

Here is an example I threw together that doesn't account for using sorting layers, just sorting order.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RayCastMultiple : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Current active camera
    public Camera MainCamera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        if(MainCamera == null)
            Debug.LogError("No MainCamera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            var mouseSelection = CheckForObjectUnderMouse();
            if(mouseSelection == null)
                Debug.Log("nothing selected by mouse");
            else
                Debug.Log(mouseSelection.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private GameObject CheckForObjectUnderMouse()
    {
        Vector2 touchPostion = MainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D[] allCollidersAtTouchPosition = Physics2D.RaycastAll(touchPostion, Vector2.zero);

        SpriteRenderer closest = null; //Cache closest sprite reneder so we can assess sorting order
        foreach(RaycastHit2D hit in allCollidersAtTouchPosition)
        {
            if(closest == null) // if there is no closest assigned, this must be the closest
            {
                closest = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                continue;
            }

            var hitSprite = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

            if(hitSprite == null)
                continue; //If the object has no sprite go on to the next hitobject

            if(hitSprite.sortingOrder > closest.sortingOrder)
                closest = hitSprite;
        }

        return closest != null ? closest.gameObject : null;
    }

}
```

This is pretty much just a duplicate of my answer here: [Game Dev Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116573/how-to-check-mouse-is-not-over-any-object-in-unity/116576#116576)

Comment: This is a poor answer, even if it does work. The OP is clearly using an event model yet your solution completely bypasses this and uses a polling model.

Comment: How would you do this using an event model?